# Why is $\tan^{-1} (\tan(4 \pi/5)) = - \pi/5 $ not $4 \pi/5$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$f^{-1} (f(x))=x$ and $f(f^{-1} (x)) =x$ by definition of inverse function.

So why isn't  $\tan^{-1} (\tan(4 \pi/5)) = 4 \pi/5$?

Comment: Learn something about **domain** and **image** of a function.

Comment: Please use the mathematical name of the function, $\color{red}{\arctan}$.  `tan` has no inverse since it is not a bijection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the tangent function is *not injective*, it doesn't strictly speaking have an inverse function.

The notation $\tan^{-1}$ for the arctangent is therefore a bit of a misnormer -- it is not really the inverse of the full tangent function, but is defined as the inverse function of the *restriction* of the tangent function to the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. This restriction *is* injective, but is not defined at $\frac45\pi$, which is why its inverse doesn't take that value.

Comment: What about the other trig functions' inverses? Do they have a similar restriction?

Comment: @user122965: Yes. The arcsine (notated $\sin^{-1}$) is the inverse of the restriction of $\sin$ to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and the arccosine (notated $\cos^{-1}$) it the inverse of the restriction of $\cos$ to $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: How did you find the restriction for the inverse tri functions?

Comment: @user122965: It's not something I "find" -- just a convention I happen to know what is. The convention for each of the three functions is the way it is because those intervals are the _largest_ intervals that you can restrict each of the trig functions to and still get something injective, if the interval has to contain $(0,\pi/2)$ (i.e. the acute angles that the elementary right-triangle definitions of the trig functions make sense for).

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions for $\tan^{-1}$ function. One in the principal quadrant and the other is in the vertically opposite quadrant. In your case they lie in second and fourth quadrants. So both solutions are correct.